# Preventing file overwrites from other committers in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, configuration

The problem arises when one developer has a file-A open and begins to edit it. Another developer has also written into file-A and committed into trunk.

The first developer svn-updates and file-A is now updated in his working directory but he has already started working on file-A based on the last revision. If she saves the file and then commits, it will overwrite all changes made by the other developer.

In this situation, what can be done to prevent it? Any good workflows? Will a DVCS help resolve this type of conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you save the files in your working directory before doing an update to it then you won't have the problem you are describing.

I would think you should be able to roll back your local directory to the previous version by doing a:

> svn update -r [revision_number]

Then saving the file you are editing, then doing a:

> svn update

which should then either merge in the changes or prompt you that there is a conflict in the local directory.

Once you resolve the conflict (if there is one) you can commit back to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Doing an SVN update should either gracefully merge the other developer's changes into the first developer's working copy, or it should signal a "merge conflict".  At which point you resolve the conflicts manually, before committing.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I'm pointing out the situation where the developer opens revision 1 of the file and starts to edit it in her IDE. Then does an SVN up before saving that file and the file is now revision 2. She then proceeds to save the file that's open in her IDE and that will now overwrite the new changes.

Comment: @lamp_scaler: That's really just up to the developer to be careful; no VCS can deal with unsaved local changes.  Even if she does do that, it's trivial to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You set requires-lock on each files properties. This forces each developer to lock the file before editing it.

It's normally not they way you wanna work but if you development process requires it then go for it.

Comment: Back to CVS (RCS?) instead of stupidity elimination? Bad idea

Answer (score 0):

> In this situation, what can be done to prevent it? Any good workflows?

Just *rational* workflow:

- **Do not update** the WC **without saving** your edits
- Use good editor, which auto-reload opened file, if it was was changed in background (losing changes teach "Save often, save before update" extremely fast)